# Using pthreads to speed up the processing of counting prime numbers from 0 to N. Am I using them correctly?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm writing code that counts Prime numbers from 0 to N utilizing 8 pthreads to speed up the process. I've done some research on multithreading in C online, but I'm still not sure if I'm using them correctly in this case. Are they actually speeding up the execution time of my program? If I'm not mistaken, pthread execute their functions simultaneously, no?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM_COUNT 800
#define NUM_THREADS 8

int counter = 0; //counter to count primes
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

//function to find primes
int is_prime(int n) {
    if (n < 2)return 0;
    if (n == 2)return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0)return 0;
    for (int i=3; i < n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void *PrintPrimes(void *threadid) {
    int thread_start, thread_end;
    int thread_id = (int)threadid; //store thread id in thread_id
    thread_start = thread_id*(NUM_COUNT/NUM_THREADS); //determine where individual thread begins searching for primes
    thread_end = thread_start+(NUM_COUNT/NUM_THREADS); //determine where thread ends searching for primes
    for(int n = thread_start; n < thread_end; n++) {
        if (is_prime(n)) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            counter++;
            printf("the number of primes is currently %d\n", counter);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, PrintPrimes, (void *)i);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You need to [*wait*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) for the threads to finish. Or [*detach*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) them to make them independent.

Comment: Implementing a prime number sieve might be a more effective way to speed this particular computation than is deploying pthreads, provided you have enough memory for the sieve data structure.

Comment: in general, threads do not 'actually' execute in parallel.  So the necessary 'context switch'ing will actually result in the program running slower.  So using threads is useful when separate events are being handled (like a server with multiple clients) or when the thread will spend a lot of time waiting of I/O to complete

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {`  When the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: OT: when calling functions like: `pthread_create()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few problems with the code:

1. You never call `pthread_join()` on the threads, which means your program will exit immediately after spawning the threads, rather than waiting for them to complete -- probably not what you want.  You should add a second for loop like this one to the bottom of your `main()` function:

   ```
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(&threads[i], NULL);
    }
   ```
2. The call to `pthread_exit()` in `main()` is unnecessary, you can get rid of it.  (It's meant to be called from within a spawned pthread to cause the thread to exit, there's no point to calling it from the main thread)
3. Calling `printf()` from within your threads' computation-loop is going to slow down the computations greatly (to the point where you are no longer measuring the performance of your actual computations at all, rather you are only really measuring the speed at which `printf()` and the stdout subsystem execute)
4. Keeping a shared/global `counter` that you have to guard with a mutex every time you find a new prime number isn't terribly efficient; better to declare a local/non-shared counter-variable for each thread, and increment that.  Then at the end of the threads execution, you can add the thread's local-counter to the shared/global counter just one time, and thereby avoid paying the synchronization-penalty that comes with a lock()/unlock() sequence more than once per thread.

Comment: @bruno that's an ugly thing to do, and I suspect it invokes undefined behavior, but it will generally work.

Comment: @bruno That's one of the *very* few occasions that it's usually considered okay to cast integer values to and from a pointer. To be safer one could double-cast it to/from `intptr_t`.

Comment: @bruno, that's a pretty common way to convey an integer argument to a thread start function, and to the best of my knowledge, it works as intended on every implementation that supports pthreads in the first place.

Comment: This was very informative! Thank you. Side note: You were not kidding about `printf()` slowing execution time!

Comment: I'm not proud of how I handled the casting the integer in the thread function, but I couldn't come up with a more efficient way. I'll have to revisit that.

Comment: One common alternative would be to declare an array of objects on the stack in main() (e.g. an array of ints in this case), populate the array with the argument-data you want to send to the threads, and then pass each thread a pointer to its corresponding entry in the array.